# Implement "DropBox" (application) Functionality in C#

Tags: c#, filesystems

I'm trying to implement a service application to sync directories across port 80 on multiple boxes.  Does anyone know of any .net libraries that provide this functionality, I'm sure there must be some ?

I've tried some similar things with the  FileSystemWatcher Class but have had issues with this.

Any ideas ...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576923/dropbox-com-api-for-net

Comment: @craig1231: This is a rather different question...

Comment: C# is a poor choice for this sort of project, since you're going to be intimately working with low-level filesystem APIs (at least if you want to be efficient).

Comment: @Ben Voigt assuming it was to be in a different language what language / libraries would you suggest ?

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna: C++ is by far the easiest way to call Windows APIs.  With Visual C++, you can write a class in C++/CLI and call that from C#.  I think you may be able to find some such code already, look for .NET wrappers for the NTFS journal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23217)

I haven't used it in a project personally but I think this may be a viable solution.

Comment: Doesn't look like this helps with the "detection of file changes" part at all.

Comment: The File Synchronization Provider component has change detection capabilities. I don't think it raises events in the same way that the FileSystemWatcher does but the OP said he had problems with FSW in the past anyhow.

Comment: I had looked at this it seems to have pretty mixed reviews